# How to retain corner rounding while resizing rounded rectangles, just like in Adobe Illustrator in PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, microsoft-powerpoint

I am using PowerPoint to create mockups of user interfaces.

It's easy if you use regular rectangles with sharp corners.

It's hard when you use rounded rectangles.

Is there a way to retain the corner rounding of a rounded rectangle while resizing it?

Currently, if you resize a rounded rectangle, the rounded corners get larger / smaller appropriately. This is Not what I want... I want to resize just the width and height of the rectangle, without changing the rounded border radius. Just like in CSS. Or just like in Illustrator. But in PowerPoint.

Comment: Would a VBA macro that sets the corner radius to a specific size be acceptable for you?

Comment: Yes, especially if it's a one-step process. e.g. Select several rectangles. All rectangles will follow the rounded corner of the first rectangle selected.

Answer (score 7):

VBA macros are required for solving the problem.

If you have never before had to work with VBA (lucky you),
you can learn the subject in the Microsoft article of :
[Getting Started with VBA in PowerPoint 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814734%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

You will need the following two macros : GetShapeRounding and SetShapeRounding.
Both macros assume that that the rounded rectangle is the currently-selected
shape. The first macro calculates the shape's radius size in points and
the second sets the selected shape to this radius.

Using the macros is by :

1. Create the rounded-rectangle and select it (or leave it selected)
2. Run the first macro to calculate the radius
3. Resize the rounded-rectangle and leave it selected
4. Run the second macro to set its corners to the calculated radius

Here are the macros :

```
Dim sngRadius As Single ' Radius size in points

Sub GetShapeRounding()
Dim oSh As Shape
Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
With oSh
  If .Width < .Height Then
    sngRadius = .Width * .Adjustments(1)
  Else ' .Width >= .Height
    sngRadius = .Height * .Adjustments(1)
  End If
End With
MsgBox sngRadius
Set oSh = Nothing
End Sub

Sub SetShapeRounding()
Dim oSh As Shape
Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
With oSh
  If .Width < .Height Then
    .Adjustments(1) = sngRadius / .Width
  Else ' .Width >= .Height
    .Adjustments(1) = sngRadius / .Height
  End If
End With
Set oSh = Nothing
End Sub
```

Tested on PowerPoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with PowerPoint out of the box.

You'd have to write a small VBA macro for it.

There are PowerPoint add-ins that let you unify the corner radius (give every box the same radius). Our is one of them: [www.veodin.com/slideproof](http://www.veodin.com/slideproof)

Comment: I cannot find a screenshot of the feature you just mentioned... Is there a more detailed product page describing the 80+ features?

Comment: The webpage is behind http://www.slideshare.net/Veodin/veodin-slide-proofmanual/#29 there is 14 day free trial. let me know if you want to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, since this question is quite old but still Google landing search here so a very quick answer that Microsoft Powerpoint 2016-2018 has a 'adjustable point' over the border while you creating a shape to manage 'radius size'.

Refer gif:

[image]

Cheers! for all Non VBA Lovers :)

Comment: But the adjustable point moves (and hence the radius changes) if the height of the box is changed. There doesn't seem to be a way of locking the adjustable point

Comment: yes right, but still you can manage the radius size by dragging them on the corner.